# Spring MVC Image Response can not be copied and pasted in Word and other applications

Tags: java, spring, image, spring-mvc, copy-paste

I have an image saved as a blob in a database. I send this image with a Spring MVC controller to the browser. That part works well with the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/img/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Image image = imageRepository.findOne(id);
    if (image != null) {
             HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
             headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
             return new ResponseEntity<>(image.getData(), headers, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
    return null;
}
```

But when i try to copy the image and paste it in, for example, Word, there is just a blank square. I tried to paste the image in Paint.NET and there it works again.

I tried some other methods of sending the image to the browser, for example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/img/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getImage(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {

  Image image = imageRepository.findOne(id);
  if (image != null) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(image.getData());
    response.reset();
    response.setContentLength(image.getData().length);
    response.setContentType("image/png");
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    try {
      OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
      IOUtils.copy(bis, outputStream);  
      bis.close();
      outputStream.flush();          
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This works also well with browser but copy and paste in applications like word does also not work. I'm clueless what i can try or where the mistake could be.

Saving the Image and inserting it in the application works but is unfortunately not an option.

Does anyone know what else i can try or what could go wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok i solved it. The problem in this case was actually the SSL-Connection forced by the Server. I set up a SecurityConstraint for the URL-Path for the images that excludes it from using SSL and now it works.

Edit: I'm still confused why copy and paste worked in Paint.NET but not in Word...